# What to use instead ini in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, settings, ini

There must be a program that should generate WORD document (but that's not the point). It generates a document by data that the user writes in the program. And sometimes there is need to close application and do some other work and user don't want to lose all progress. And here we must keep all the "changes" that user have entered. Previously, I have saved all .ini file (under the instruction http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C) it was enough for me for test, but in real cases ini was not enough, because if I save the textbox with multiline so record to inin file goes wrong, and when reading ini file - readed was only the first line and then only the first 255 characters.

Here is an example of what should be saved:

1. information about all checked checkboxes radiobuttons etc. (in
   INI-expample I show it in CHECKOUTS and COMPARING sections)
2. the data from all textboxes on the main form (MAIN section)
3. most importantly, objects of 'implementation' and 'screens' class.

Now about class 'implementation': Each implementation may have a name, description, status, and a list of links to screenshots. To do this, I created a listbox with list of screenshots for each implementation (ScreenList) and a separate listbox for all implementations. Ie when I fill the data I store object in listbox, and then if I need I can just get access to it. And when I save a list of all implementations into ini I first of all write the number of all implementations to be able get access in loops (for, while etc) to each object (all in INI and CODE examples: Section IMPLEMENTATIONS, IMPLEMENTATION_n ...)

And the question is: how to save these Data? As I know Microsoft has abandoned ini and use the xml, but I can't google it correctly. Someone suggested I use serialization of data in xml, but as far as I could google - Serialization is used only for one object of class, and I have a lot of these objects are, othervide I still have and values ​​of all the checkboxes and more. Ie I need to save all the values ​​of controls , all the objects of classes implement and screen, and then read these values ​​and write them right back to where they were taken . How to do that?

Code examples:

```
//........save object to listbox
Implement imp = new Implement(impName.Text, impDescr.Text, impStatus.Text, ScreenList);
listBox1.Items.Add(imp);
//......

//in implement class, Screens is list of screenshots that is get from another listbox
private List<string> _Screens = new List<string>();
public Implement(string Name, string Description, string Status, ListBox Screen)
{
    _Name = Name;
    _Description = Description;
    _Status = Status;
    for(int i=0;i<Screen.Items.Count;i++)
    {
        _Screens.Add(Screen.Items[i].ToString());
    }
}

//....getting access to implementation
Implement imp = (Implement)listBox1.SelectedItem;
....
```

Ini example:

```
[MAIN]
Languages=Polish
Comment=Comment lalarar larl alrlalrl
Status=Correct
[CHECKOUTS]
Enable=True
SLDoc=False
SLDocTab=True
SaveDoc=True
LoadDoc=False
SendDoc=False
Correctly=True
CorrNum=50
[COMPARING]
Enable=True
NoDif=False
Declar=True
UnDecl=False
UnDeclDESCR=
[IMPLEMENTATIONS]
COUNT=2
[IMPLEMENTATION_0]
Name=Implement 1 CORRECT
Descr=text text test text
Status=Correct
ScreenCount=2
Screen_0=C:\1.png
Screen_1=C:\2.png
[IMPLEMENTATION_1]
Name=IMPLEMENT 2 INCORRECT
Descr=lala
Status=Incorrect
ScreenCount=2
Screen_0=C:\2.png
Screen_1=C:\3.jpg
[SCREENS]
COUNT=2
[SCREEN_0]
Descr=Screen 1
Screen=C:\1.png
[SCREEN_1]
Descr=Screen 2
Screen=C:\1.png
```

Comment: Don't you think this question is a bit too broad ?

Comment: have you tried using app.config file ?

Comment: looks like a good example of "where to use xml" when you want to get a readable and hierachical serialisation...

Comment: use a app.config file instead of INI...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you should take a look at **settings** mechanism in c#.

I hope that [this chapter of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is create some kind of `Settings` object. This should be a class that either has a specific property (or class for nested values) for each setting you like (e.g. `public string Language {get; set; }`) or you take a more generic way by using two dictionaries `Dictionary<string, string>` (for simple values), `Dictionary<string, Settings>` (a recursive structure for complex types).

Then your form should be able to create such a settings object an fill it with the desired data it needs to recreate the current state and it should be able to take such a settings object and change its current state to this settings object by setting all inner variable to the values within this object.

The next step would be to make this object serializable by either using [XML serialization](http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization) or [Data Contract](http://wcftutorial.net/data-contract.aspx) or whatever you like. Then you can write/load this object to/from disk and afterwards push it into the class that needs this state.